# Is the www2 non-mirror subdomain affects the SEO?

Tags: seo

I have a client with two CMS (Hubspot and WordPress) on two different subdomains.

WordPress: www.domain.tld
Hubspot: www2.domain.tld

The WordPress environment is used for the main website and the Hubspot is only used for the blog (yeah, I know, it's strange). The client wants to keep the Hubspot environment, but I'm not sure about the subdomain actually used (www2).

The www2 isn't used like a mirror.

I want to know if a subdomain like www2 affects the SEO.

Thx,

Comment: www2 is a horribly chosen subdomain name.   It is far more common to use `blog.example.com` and `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

www2 is treated like a subdomain as you said. Google will identify www2.example.com and word.example.com as the same thing, subdomains of the parent domain.

It's fine if your client wants to use subdomains on his website for various reasons. As long as it's not duplicate content as you said, it should be fine.

Subdomains have different domain authority and page authority than that of the parent domain. So www2.example.com and example.com will be treated as different entities.

Comment: "Subdomains have different domain authority and page authority than that of the parent domain": Do you have an official link from Google/Bing/Yahoo for that statement? Since when does the "root domain" have a different page authority than a subdomain like www.root-domain ?

Comment: "Subdomains SOMETIMES inherit and pass link/trust/quality/ranking metrics between one another.

Subfolders ALWAYS inherit and pass link/trust/quality/ranking metrics across the same subdomain" - Rand Fishkin of MOZ

Comment: Sometimes/maybe/could and should are different than what you stated in your anwser: "Subdomains have different domain authority and page authority". Also Rand Fishkin of MOZ may be an authority in the SEO world, but that statement (if he made it, link missing) is in no way any official statement by a search engine.